# How to install missing firmware for an Creative Labs Audigy2 soundcard?

Tags: 11.04, soundcard, firmware

I have an [E-MU 1616m PCI Soundcard](http://www.creative.com/emu/products/product.aspx?category=505&pid=19007) and recently made the switch from Windows to Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty). From a fresh install, everything works good except for a small error when I boot up that says it cannot find the firmware for my soundcard.

Can anyone please help me learn what I need to do to get my soundcard working again?

Output from `dmesg | grep emu` is:

```
[   22.083208] emu1010: Special config.
[   22.083289] emu1010: EMU_HANA_ID = 0x3f
[   22.083291] emu1010: filename emu/emu1010b.fw testing
[   22.119132] firmware: emu/emu1010b.fw not found. Err = -2
[   22.119136] emu1010: Loading Firmware file emu/emu1010b.fw failed
```

`ls /lib/firmware/emu` says that the directory does not exist!

I am new to Ubuntu and Linux in general so I am not sure what other information I can provide.

I found this link on [installing the ALSA driver for the E-MU 1616m PCI](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix%3aModule-emu10k1-fpga), but I am worried I will wreck something trying to install from source and things will go all Ubuntu Crazy on me.

**Some more system information:**

`lspci | grep audio`

`04:07.0 Multimedia audio controller: Creative Labs SB0400 Audigy2 Value`

and

`lshw`

```
   *-multimedia UNCLAIMED
        description: Multimedia audio controller
        product: SB0400 Audigy2 Value
        vendor: Creative Labs
        physical id: 7
        bus info: pci@0000:04:07.0
        version: 00
        width: 32 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: cap_list
        configuration: latency=32 maxlatency=20 mingnt=2
        resources: ioport:cf00(size=64)
```

`modinfo snd` and `modinfo soundcore` both return results so they are there as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to download and copy the firmware, compile it and copy the firmware into the correct folder location for the kernel to load when your PC boots.

The error message you have in your question `Loading Firmware file emu/emu1010b.fw` is very useful.

Install the build-essential package:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Acquire an alsa-firmware tarball (> 1.0.14) from the ALSA project's FTP server, for example:

```
wget ftp://ftp.alsa-project.org/pub/firmware/alsa-firmware-1.0.24.1.tar.bz2
```

Extract the tarball and create the firmware:

```
tar xvf alsa-firmware-1.0.24.1.tar.bz2
cd alsa-firmware-1.0.24.1
./configure
cd emu && make
```

Install the firmware on your system:

```
sudo su
mkdir -p /lib/firmware/emu
cp *fw /lib/firmware/emu
```

Reload the snd-emu10k1 module:

```
modprobe -r snd-emu10k1-synth snd-emu10k1 ; modprobe snd-emu10k1
```

[source](http://wiki.debian.org/snd-emu10k1#general)

Comment: I just had to change the folder where I make and copy the firmware files to `/lib/firmware/emu` instead of `/usr/local/lib/firmware/emu` and everything works great! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

E-MU 0404 PCI no sound.
Workaround - need setup Medibuntu repos and install `alsa-firmware`.
[Medibuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Medibuntu#Adding%20the%20Repositories).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential information about how to do this, and provide the link for reference.