# Only "Dummy output" (sound) in Ubuntu 20.04 after reboot - Broken driver / module

Tags: drivers, sound, kernel, 20.04, alsa

**EDIT**:
*This appears to have turned in a sort of canonical set of commands to start diagnosing audio issues.*

---

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 for over a month now.
After a reboot, I have no more sound and WiFi. Note that this is different from many other posts, which seem to have had no sound at all, after an upgrade. In this case, sound stopped working only after a reboot.

As for the sound, **I seem to not have the appropriate kernel modules for sound**, so I guess the most likely solution would come from making the modules available (it seems I have two sound cards).
I will try to include below (1) as much info as possible related to the copious posts with similar problems.

I am listing below (2) the posts that I consider most useful at the current point of the fixing work-in-progress.

And I am listing below (3) other posts that I checked when the grass was higher.

---

(1) **Info about my broken system, along with a comparison with what I see in a working system that I managed to put together.**

1. No `/proc/asound` directory.

   **Versus**

```
    $ cat /proc/asound/cards
     0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                          HDA Intel PCH at 0x604b108000 irq 159
     1 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                          HDA NVidia at 0xa4000000 irq 17
```

2. `$ lsmod | grep snd` outputs nothing.

   **Versus** (also compare with [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231426/no-sound-on-upgrade-18-04-20-04-only-have-dummy-output))

```
    $ lsmod | grep snd_hda_intel
    snd_hda_intel          53248  10
    snd_intel_dspcfg       24576  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
    snd_hda_codec         131072  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_hdac_hda
    snd_hda_core           90112  9 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
    snd_pcm               106496  9 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
    snd                    90112  33 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,thinkpad_acpi,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
```

3. Kernel modules

```
    $ dpkg -L linux-modules-$(uname -r) | grep snd
    /lib/modules/5.4.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-dummy.ko
    /lib/modules/5.4.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-midi-emul.ko
    /lib/modules/5.4.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-midi-event.ko
    /lib/modules/5.4.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-midi.ko
    /lib/modules/5.4.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-virmidi.ko
    /lib/modules/5.4.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq.ko
    /lib/modules/5.4.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-compress.ko
    /lib/modules/5.4.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-hrtimer.ko
    /lib/modules/5.4.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-hwdep.ko
    /lib/modules/5.4.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-pcm-dmaengine.ko
    /lib/modules/5.4.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-pcm.ko
    /lib/modules/5.4.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-rawmidi.ko
    /lib/modules/5.4.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-seq-device.ko
    /lib/modules/5.4.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-timer.ko
    /lib/modules/5.4.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd.ko
    /lib/modules/5.4.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/drivers/pcsp/snd-pcsp.ko
    /lib/modules/5.4.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/pci/snd-ens1370.ko
```

**Versus** exactly the same

**How can I check if any of this is what I need?**

**How can I check if any of this corresponds to those from Intel listed in item #2 above?**

**How can I load these modules?**

4. `inxi`

```
    $ inxi -SA
    System:    Host: Hydrus1 Kernel: 5.4.0-40-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Gnome 3.36.1 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
    Audio:     Device-1: Intel 6 Series/C200 Series Family High Definition Audio driver: N/A 
               Device-2: NVIDIA GF104 High Definition Audio driver: N/A
```

**Versus** (also compare with [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240560/dummy-output-after-standby-since-upgrading-to-ubuntu-20-04))

```
    $ inxi -SA
    System:    Host: ViaLactea Kernel: 5.4.0-40-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Console: tty 0 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa)
    Audio:     Device-1: Intel Cannon Lake PCH cAVS driver: snd_hda_intel
               Device-2: NVIDIA GP107GL High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
               Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-40-generic
```

5. `lspci`

   ```
   $ lspci -nnk | grep -A 1 Audio
   00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1c20] (rev 04)
       DeviceName:  Onboard Audio
       Subsystem: Dell 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [1028:04a4]
   00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1c10] (rev b4)
   --
   01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GF104 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:0beb] (rev a1)
       Subsystem: Dell GF104 High Definition Audio Controller [1028:04a4]
   03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 [8086:422b] (rev 35)
   ```

**Versus**

```
    $ lspci -nnk | grep -n -A 4 Audio
    49:00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS [8086:a348] (rev 10)
    50-     Subsystem: Lenovo Cannon Lake PCH cAVS [17aa:225f]
    51-     Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    52-     Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci
    53-00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller [8086:a323] (rev 10)
    --
    67:01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller [10de:0fb9] (rev a1)
    68-     Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    69-     Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
    70-70:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:525a] (rev 01)
    71-     Subsystem: Lenovo RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader [17aa:225f]
```

6. System (**Versus** exactly the same kernel)

   ```
   $ uname -a
   Linux Hydrus1 5.4.0-40-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 23 00:01:04 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
   ```
7. Test sound

   ```
   $ aplay -l
   aplay: device_list:274: no soundcards found...
   ```

**Versus**

```
    $ aplay -l
    **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
    card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC285 Analog [ALC285 Analog]
      Subdevices: 0/1
      Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
    card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
      Subdevices: 1/1
      Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
    ...
```

8. `lshw`

```
        $ lshw -C multimedia
        WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
          *-multimedia UNCLAIMED    
               description: Audio device
               product: GF104 High Definition Audio Controller
               vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
               physical id: 0.1
               bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
               version: a1
               width: 32 bits
               clock: 33MHz
               capabilities: bus_master cap_list
               configuration: latency=0
               resources: memory:e0080000-e0083fff
          *-multimedia UNCLAIMED
               description: Audio device
               product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
               vendor: Intel Corporation
               physical id: 1b
               bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
               version: 04
               width: 64 bits
               clock: 33MHz
               capabilities: bus_master cap_list
               configuration: latency=0
               resources: memory:e1e50000-e1e53fff
        WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240560/dummy-output-after-standby-since-upgrading-to-ubuntu-20-04) it is quoted (note the driver)

```
    $ sudo lshw -C multimedia
      *-multimedia              
           description: Audio device
           product: GP104 High Definition Audio Controller
           vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
           physical id: 0.1
           bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
           version: a1
           width: 32 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
           configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
           resources: irq:17 memory:f7080000-f7083fff
```

9. `alsa` packages

   ```
   $ dpkg -l | grep alsa
   ii  alsa-base                                     1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5                all          ALSA driver configuration files
   ii  alsa-tools-gui                                1.1.7-1ubuntu1                      amd64        GUI based ALSA utilities for specific hardware
   ii  alsa-topology-conf                            1.2.2-1                             all          ALSA topology configuration files
   ii  alsa-ucm-conf                                 1.2.2-1ubuntu0.1                    all          ALSA Use Case Manager configuration files
   ii  alsa-utils                                    1.2.2-1ubuntu1                      amd64        Utilities for configuring and using ALSA
   ii  gstreamer1.0-alsa:amd64                       1.16.2-4                            amd64        GStreamer plugin for ALSA
   ii  libsox-fmt-alsa:amd64                         14.4.2+git20190427-2                amd64        SoX alsa format I/O library
   ```
10. No sound either if I plug earphones.
11. I have no `timidity-daemon` to remove.
12. Attempt reload

    ```
    $ sudo alsa force-reload
    [sudo] password for user1: 
    Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: (none loaded).
    Loading ALSA sound driver modules: (none to reload).
    ```
13. modprobe

    ```
    $ grep intel /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf 
    options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
    ```

---

(2) **Related and possibly useful posts**

[Unable to get sound working. Ubuntu Server 14.04.3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/719548/unable-to-get-sound-working-ubuntu-server-14-04-3)

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=221745

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1684576

[How to load "snd-hda-intel" at startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/759174/how-to-load-snd-hda-intel-at-startup)

---

(3) **Other related posts**

https://www.alsa-project.org/wiki/Matrix:Module-hda-intel

https://askubuntu.com/a/1244118/226614 . Recent post, accepted answer. Suggests using a `ppa` for fixing. I am not sure this can get things worse...

https://askubuntu.com/a/1249071/226614 . Recent post. Suggests using
sudo setfacl -m u:user1:rw /dev/snd/*
Tried this, didn't help.

https://askubuntu.com/a/847954/226614 . Old post, accepted answer. Suggests installing `alsa-firmware-loaders` and `alsa-base`. I am not sure this still applies...

[How to install missing firmware for an Creative Labs Audigy2 soundcard?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60763/how-to-install-missing-firmware-for-an-creative-labs-audigy2-soundcard/60794#60794) . Also old post. Also suggests `UNCLAIMED` device is due to firmware issues.
**Why would the problem appear after a reboot?**

[No sound on upgrade (18.04 -> 20.04) only have "dummy output"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231426/no-sound-on-upgrade-18-04-20-04-only-have-dummy-output)

[Dummy output after standby since upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240560/dummy-output-after-standby-since-upgrading-to-ubuntu-20-04)

[Internal speaker (Audio) is not working in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS after upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230363/20-04-internal-speaker-audio-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts-after-upgradi)

[Ubuntu 20.04 - No sound](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231524/ubuntu-20-04-no-sound)

[Soundcard not detected by pulseaudio (but by alsa)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230383/soundcard-not-detected-by-pulseaudio-but-by-alsa)

[How to install missing firmware for an Creative Labs Audigy2 soundcard?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60763/how-to-install-missing-firmware-for-an-creative-labs-audigy2-soundcard/60794#60794)

https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/

Comment: The package ```linux-modules-kernel-version-generic``` should install ```snd``` drivers for you.And looks like **Intel Centrino Ultimate-N** is no longer supported and I don't know which driver should be used for that , but installing the above package might help.And **SNDYBRDG** (Sandy bridge) has nothing to do with **sound**, it's in fact the name of the microarchitecture used by intel in the second generation of **Core** processors.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi - Please check edited OP. I have included the contents of the package you mention, a few questions and comments. You may know how to follow up.

Comment: `modprobe --show-depends snd_hda_intel` . BTW the right forum for alsa/sound problems would be alsa forum (https://www.alsa-project.org/wiki/Main_Page). BTW: There exists a beautiful script that uploads all necessary info for debugging sound problems --> https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/AlsaInfo ; you can also install it with `sudo apt install alsa-utils` . Did you check if your card is supported: https://www.alsa-project.org/wiki/Matrix:Main ?

Comment: @abu_bua - Your comment helped me find the solution, which I posted. I suggest you post it as an answer. I will perform further tests, and if everything is ok I would award to your answer.
Thanks!

Comment: Files in the `/proc` map to processes running on your system, so you should only have `/proc/aplay` when alsa has play processes active (it is playing sound). Same with `/dev` and devices.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**EDIT**:
[Avoid missing kernel linux-modules-extra-XX-generic when updating kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1265137/avoid-missing-kernel-linux-modules-extra-xx-generic-when-updating-kernel)
may help avoiding the problem in the future, in some cases. (I actually ran into this same problem later again after a new automatic update, and then identified the missing package).

---

**Summary**: I managed to

1. Learn which files my system was missing.
   **This was my main hurdle, solved with the help of [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258510/only-dummy-output-sound-in-ubuntu-20-04-after-reboot#comment2129564_1258510), now posted as [an answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1259818/226614). The rest was easy**.
2. Learn which package holds them.
3. Install it.

---

After trying many things,
I have solved the problem.
It was essential to have, in addition to my broken system **S1**, a similar working system **S2** available.
I was very lucky to have this, and I guess it might have taken me tons of extra time otherwise.

Detailing the list of steps above:

1. In **S1**:

   ```
    $ modprobe --show-depends snd_hda_intel
    modprobe: FATAL: Module snd_hda_intel not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-40-generic
   ```

   In **S2**:

   ```
    $ modprobe --show-depends snd_hda_intel
    insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/soundcore.ko
    install /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }
    insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-timer.ko
    install /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; }
    insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-hwdep.ko
    insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/hda/snd-hda-core.ko
    insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/pci/hda/snd-hda-codec.ko
    insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/hda/snd-intel-dspcfg.ko
    insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/pci/hda/snd-hda-intel.ko
   ```

   I had the first three `.ko` files in my **S1**, but not the last four.
2. So I checked the owner package in **S2** for the last four files.

   ```
    $ dpkg -S /lib/modules/5.4.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/hda/snd-hda-core.ko
    linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-40-generic: /lib/modules/5.4.0-40-generic/kernel/sound/hda/snd-hda-core.ko
   ```

   which was the same for the other three files missing in **S1**.
   I checked and this package was not installed in **S1**.
3. I `apt-get`'d the package, rebooted, and now everything seems to be back to normal.

My guess is that the package was present during the time sound worked, and for some strange reason it got uninstalled (or removed, or...) from the `dkpg` database, or...?

Notes:

1. I had also kernel `5.4.0-39` in **S1**, and sound didn't work in this kernel either, prior to the fixing which worked.
   It turned out that `linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-39-generic` was not installed either.
2. On (Compiled) Kernel Drivers vs. (Loadable) Kernel Drivers / Modules: see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47208/what-is-the-difference-between-kernel-drivers-and-kernel-modules).

Comment: If your problem is solved you should check, otherwise it still appears as unanswered questions! Hence please mark the answer of your choice with a cross (it's under the up-/downvote icon) !

Comment: @abu_bua - I know. As mentioned in my comment, it is *most likely* solved. I will perform further checks (it may take a couple of days... working on other stuff as well) and accept. Rest assured, I value the system of acknowledging contributions in SE sites, it is useful for the community.

Comment: I use git to troubleshoot in these circumstances. if you cd to root & run git init, you turn your fs into a git repo.  i make commits regularly. It is sort of like taking snapshots, as you can always mount the filesystem to another linux fs and run `git revert` to restore to an earlier point / commit. Better still, you can use a diff program from the terminal and grep the result to see any changes to the system. You need to have a recent commit, though.

Answer (score 17):

Try to check if all dependencies are correct:

```
modprobe --show-depends snd_hda_intel
```

And check if the kernel module exists:

```
find /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/sound -name snd-hda-intel.ko
```

BTW a better forum for alsa/sound problems would be the alsa forum ([alsa-project.org/wiki/Main_Page](https://alsa-project.org/wiki/Main_Page)).

BTW: There exists a beautiful script that uploads all necessary info for debugging sound problems --> [wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/AlsaInfo](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/AlsaInfo); you can also install it with `sudo apt install alsa-utils`.
Run the script `alsa-info`, which will help you to print all necessary info for future problems with a minimum of effort.

As the kernel module itself is missing you have to install it e.g. via this package:

```
sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)
```

Comment: It is not the kernel that is missing, but *some of* the files on which the kernel module driver depends. Which of those files are missing and what package holds them is shown in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1259815/226614).

Comment: In ubuntu focal this has to be `linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)` because `uname -r` prints a string that completes in `-generic`. To be used like this: `sudo apt-get install linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)`

Answer (score 14):

Had the same issue, I just did:

```
sudo killall timidity
```

Then the sound came back.

But after reboot, there is no sound again.

Then I figured out the proper way of disabling timidity:

```
sudo systemctl stop timidity.service
sudo systemctl disable timidity.service
```

Comment: As said in the OP, "I have no timidity-daemon to remove."

Comment: Worked for me, so I wonder why I needed timidity in the first place...

Comment: OMG why did this work? Why have you betrayed me Timidity?!?!? You were the chosen one! You were supposed to complete my audio system! Not destroy it!!!!

Comment: This solved it for me. Would be good to understand how Timidity is causing this problem in more technical detail.

Answer (score 6):

Please try this

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall alsa-base pulseaudio
$ sudo alsa force-reload
```

Comment: Hi, I don't understand, after a fresh install of ubunut 20.04.3, always after reboot the sound "disapears" and need to run this two commands to see the internan, and hdmi outpus, but bluethoot headsets works.
Thansk you so much for share.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubunto 20.04 (only used 2nd "force-reload" command). Sound device was lost after killing "gdm3" (because of unclickable mouse behaviour). Upon getting back normal desktop only "dummy output" sound device was presend. "alsa force-reload" saved the day! Thank you!

Comment: Just running `sudo alsa force-reload` worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this sound problem with Ubuntu 20.04 after a recent hardware upgrade.

Making the following change sorted it out, perhaps it will for you as well.

Append the line

```
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
```

at the end of file `/etc/modprob.d/alsa-base.conf`.

Comment: Does this help loading the module? Should I first check somehow if I have it available? Should I add an `install` command in the same file?

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio So if it's the case , [here](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/wt9pKtqKWz/) is my complete ```alsa-base.conf``` file.It should be automatically generated however.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi - Same as I have.

Comment: I had `model=generic`. So simply changed to `model=auto` and that fixed it

Answer (score 2):

give it try, it worked for me

```
sudo apt purge timidity-daemon
```

source: [No sound on upgrade (18.04 -> 20.04) only have "dummy output"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231426/no-sound-on-upgrade-18-04-20-04-only-have-dummy-output/1235652#1235652)

Comment: As said in the OP, "I have no timidity-daemon to remove."
Plus, the question you linked is also listed in the OP.

Comment: There is an article which sheds some light behind running this command & maybe it can be of any help because I followed this article to purge the `timidity-daemon`

https://aaroalhainen.medium.com/how-i-fixed-my-ubuntu-20-04-no-audio-dummy-output-issue-eaa525838e0d

Answer (score 2):

I tried Aiden Turner's solution, because it seemed like the least potentially harmful. When I did the force-reload I heard the speakers pop, my sound device showed up in the control panel, and I had working sound after raising the volume control above the default mute level.

Rebooting the system returned me to the dummy sound problem, so I disabled the timidity service per YuanW's post above. My sound card was immediately visible, and this time it survived a reboot.

So the combination of those two solutions worked for me. Reinstall pulseaudio and alsa-base, reinitialize, and then disable timidity. It's possible that only the second step is actually necessary, but I couldn't undo it and it's mostly harmless so I'm going with the whole process.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was able to get my sound back on Ubuntu 20.04 with:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, there was only "Dummy output" in the list of sound devices.

I checked
`$ modprobe --show-depends snd_hda_intel`

and received further output:

`modprobe: FATAL: Module snd_hda_intel not found in directory /lib/modules/5.11.0-22-generic`

I started to check if the files are present (according to the correct [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1259815/706397) above). The files were present for the previous kernels - 5.4.x-xx and 5.8.x-xx.

I finally [found](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-hwe-5.11/+bug/1933723) that there are problems with the kernel 5.11 with sound devices.

Then I simply rebooted under the 5.8.

If anyone knows how to solve the problem for the 5.11 kernel, please let me know. The advices above didn't help.