# Ubuntu 21.04 No sound on new Dell Inspiron 7700 AIO

Tags: sound, 21.04

I just purchased a new Dell Inspiron 7700 AIO computer with 11th gen i7 CPU. Installed Ubuntu 21.04 and it mostly works ok. However, I have no sound from the built-in speakers, and the sound settings panel shows "Dummy Output" as the only output choice.

I've currently attached a bluetooth sound output device and am successfully using it for sound output, but I'd prefer to use the AIO's built-in speakers.

Any ideas on what I can check?

Ubuntu 21.04

kernel 5.11.0-36-generic

$ sudo lshw -C relevant outputs

```
  *-cpu                     
       description: CPU
       product: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz
       vendor: Intel Corp.
       physical id: 18
       bus info: cpu@0
       version: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz
       slot: Socket 0
       size: 1803MHz
       capacity: 4700MHz
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 100MHz

*-multimedia
       description: Audio device
       product: Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
       version: 20
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:600-5ff irq:131 memory:6013128000-601312bfff memory:6013000000-60130fffff
```

$ pacmd list-cards

```
2 card(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 24
    properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0x6013128000 irq 150"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "a0c8"
        device.product.name = "Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
```

$ sudo lspci -vvv | grep -A12 Audio

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 20) (prog-if 80)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Sound
    Subsystem: Dell Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 32, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 131
    Region 0: Memory at 6013128000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Region 4: Memory at 6013000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=55mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D3 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable+ DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [80] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 00000000fee003b8  Data: 0000
```

Comment: I found some information about Inspiron 7720 (not 7700), whose NVidia stereo controller is also not supported in any kernel versions up to 5.14. https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=f3b0e7fa47

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Thanks for the research! I do have a Nvidia MX330... and it's giving me some grief... so I wonder which audio controller is being used...

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi FYI... see my answer.

Comment: snd-hda-intel was often blacklisted in the past because there was a time when video cards' sound devices were conflicting with other sound card/devices -- in other words, it was stealing sound device '0' which many of us didn't want.  Fastforward to now when most people actually are using the on-video or on-board sound devices intel makes for dell opti-series, we have a problem of it being blacklisted.  You can quickfix this with a  "sudo modprobe snd_hda_intel" and a "sudo alsactl force-reload' but you still need to remove the blacklisted module in /etc/modprobe.d (which file varies)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix was to add the following to /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf and reboot...

```
# Enable internal audio and headphone jack on Dell Inspiron 27 7700 AIO
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi
```

One source: [Install Realtek Audio drivers in Ubuntu 20.04 (Intel Nuc nuc10i7fnh)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258583/install-realtek-audio-drivers-in-ubuntu-20-04-intel-nuc-nuc10i7fnh)

Comment: How did you find it?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I went Googling for the Realtek ALC3289 audio controller, and buried deep in the responses, was the fix. There were a few hits, and I should have noted the sources in my answer... but I was too excited over the fix :-) Found one of them... https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258583/install-realtek-audio-drivers-in-ubuntu-20-04-intel-nuc-nuc10i7fnh