# Dummy sound on NUC10i5FNH and Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: sound, soundcard

I just bought a NUC10i5FNH and installed Ubuntu 21.10 and i don't have sounds. In parameters i can see this ("Sortie fictive" == "Dummy sound"):

[image: screenshot of dummy sound]

Note this computer have a HDMI output only.

Sometime (rarely) sound works, and in place of "Dummy sound", i can see HDMI sound output (something like this).

I followed some other answers without success. There is some information :

```
salon@salon-NUC10i5FNH:~$ lsmod | grep snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_intel          53248  1
snd_intel_dspcfg       28672  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_hda_codec         147456  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_hda_core           94208  7 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_pcm               118784  10 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd                    94208  13 snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
```

```
salon@salon-NUC10i5FNH:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP cAVS [8086:02c8]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP cAVS [8086:2081]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

```
salon@salon-NUC10i5FNH:~$ tail /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
options snd-usb-ua101 index=-2
options snd-usb-us122l index=-2
options snd-usb-usx2y index=-2
# Ubuntu #62691, enable MPU for snd-cmipci
options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
# Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
```

More here (alsa-info) : http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=342abfa7a51ddcfecd57a0ea7b6b5bdeab934244

What can i do to make sound working ?

Comment: See my answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1365905/ubuntu-21-04-no-sound-on-new-dell-inspiron-7700-aio and see if it works for you... even though you don't have a Dell... Report back.

Comment: Hello @heynnema, sadly, it doesn't work. I think i will reinstall a 20.04 LTS  and cross my fingers :(

Comment: :( Tried with Ubuntu 21.10, 20.04, Debian 11 and Fedora 34. Sound don't work each time ...

Comment: When you added the line from my other answer, did you just add the line, or did you modify the existing model= line to change from auto to dell-headset-multi? Did you reboot after?

Comment: @heynnema i modified the line and rebooted yes

Comment: Then I'm sorry, I don't know. However I think the fix is the same... you just have to find out the correct model # to use.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, after running the program `pavucontrol`, HDMI sound card is permanently seen. Sound works fine now.

Comment: I have the same problem, but this doesn't fix it for me :-(