# Unable to get sound working. ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, pavucontrol

I have had this problem for a while now. I have looked around in many places for solutions. But none have worked.

this is my ALSA information

```
!!################################
!!ALSA Information Script v 0.5.0
!!################################

!!Script ran on: Tue Nov 16 15:49:58 UTC 2021
```

!!Linux Distribution
!!------------------

```
Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu 
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS" 
NAME="Ubuntu" 
ID=ubuntu 
ID_LIKE=debian 
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS"  
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

!!DMI Information
!!---------------

```
Manufacturer:      Dell Inc.
Product Name:      Vostro 3559
Product Version:   
Firmware Version:  1.2.6
System SKU:        06C2
Board Vendor:      Dell Inc.
Board Name:
```

!!ACPI Device Status Information
!!---------------

/sys/bus/acpi/devices/ACPI0003:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/ACPI000C:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/DELLABCE:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/DLLC6C2:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/DLLK06C2:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT33A1:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT33D0:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT340E:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT344B:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT3F0D:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:00/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:01/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:02/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/MSFT0101:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0103:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C02:03/status      3
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C02:04/status      3
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C09:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0A:00/status      31
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:00/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:01/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:02/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:03/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:04/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:05/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:06/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:07/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:51/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:52/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:53/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:66/status   11

!!Kernel Information
!!------------------

```
Kernel release:    5.4.0-90-generic
Operating System:  GNU/Linux
Architecture:      x86_64
Processor:         x86_64
SMP Enabled:       Yes
```

!!ALSA Version
!!------------

```
Driver version:     k5.4.0-90-generic
Library version:    1.1.3
Utilities version:  1.1.3
```

!!Loaded ALSA modules
!!-------------------

!!Sound Servers on this system
!!----------------------------

```
Pulseaudio:
      Installed - Yes (/usr/bin/pulseaudio)
      Running - No
```

!!Soundcards recognised by ALSA
!!-----------------------------

--- no soundcards ---

!!PCI Soundcards installed in the system
!!--------------------------------------

!!Modprobe options (Sound related)
!!--------------------------------

```
snd_pcsp: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
snd_atiixp_modem: index=-2
snd_intel8x0m: index=-2
snd_via82xx_modem: index=-2
snd_atiixp_modem: index=-2
snd_intel8x0m: index=-2
snd_via82xx_modem: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
snd_usb_caiaq: index=-2
snd_usb_ua101: index=-2
snd_usb_us122l: index=-2
snd_usb_usx2y: index=-2
snd_cmipci: mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
snd_hda_intel: model=laptop position_fix=1
```

!!Loaded sound module options
!!---------------------------

!!Sysfs card info
!!---------------

!!Card: /sys/class/sound/card*
Driver:
Tree:

!!ALSA Device nodes
!!-----------------

```
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  1 Nov 16 20:53 /dev/snd/seq
crw-rw----  1 root audio 116, 33 Nov 16 20:53 /dev/snd/timer
```

!!Aplay/Arecord output
!!--------------------

```
APLAY

aplay: device_list:270: no soundcards found...

ARECORD

arecord: device_list:270: no soundcards found...

!!Amixer output
!!-------------


!!Alsactl output
!!--------------

--startcollapse--
--endcollapse--
```

!!All Loaded Modules
!!------------------

```
acpi_pad
aesni_intel
ahci
aufs
autofs4
bluetooth
bnep
bpfilter
br_netfilter
bridge
btbcm
btintel
btrtl
btusb
ccm
cfg80211
cmac
coretemp
crc32_pclmul
crct10dif_pclmul
cryptd
crypto_simd
dcdbas
dell_laptop
dell_rbtn
dell_smbios
dell_smm_hwmon
dell_wmi
dell_wmi_descriptor
drm
drm_kms_helper
ebtable_filter
ebtables
ecc
ecdh_generic
fb_sys_fops
ghash_clmulni_intel
glue_helper
hid
hid_generic
hid_rmi
i2c_algo_bit
i2c_hid
i915
idma64
input_leds
intel_cstate
intel_lpss
intel_lpss_pci
intel_pch_thermal
intel_powerclamp
intel_rapl_common
intel_rapl_msr
intel_xhci_usb_role_switch
ip6_tables
ip6t_REJECT
ip6t_rt
ip6table_filter
ip_tables
ipt_REJECT
iptable_filter
iptable_mangle
iptable_nat
iwlmvm
iwlwifi
joydev
kvm
kvm_intel
ledtrig_audio
libahci
libarc4
libcrc32c
llc
lp
mac80211
mac_hid
mc
mei
mei_hdcp
mei_me
memstick
nf_conntrack
nf_conntrack_broadcast
nf_conntrack_ftp
nf_conntrack_netbios_ns
nf_conntrack_netlink
nf_defrag_ipv4
nf_defrag_ipv6
nf_log_common
nf_log_ipv4
nf_log_ipv6
nf_nat
nf_nat_ftp
nf_reject_ipv4
nf_reject_ipv6
nfnetlink
nls_iso8859_1
overlay
parport
parport_pc
pinctrl_intel
pinctrl_sunrisepoint
ppdev
psmouse
r8169
rapl
realtek
rmi_core
roles
rtsx_usb
rtsx_usb_ms
rtsx_usb_sdmmc
sch_fq_codel
serio_raw
snd
snd_hda_codec
snd_hda_core
snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep
snd_intel_dspcfg
snd_pcm
snd_rawmidi
snd_seq_device
snd_timer
snd_usb_audio
snd_usbmidi_lib
soundcore
sparse_keymap
stp
syscopyarea
sysfillrect
sysimgblt
usbhid
uvcvideo
veth
video
videobuf2_common
videobuf2_memops
videobuf2_v4l2
videobuf2_vmalloc
videodev
virt_dma
wmi
wmi_bmof
x86_pkg_temp_thermal
x_tables
xfrm_algo
xfrm_user
xt_CHECKSUM
xt_LOG
xt_MASQUERADE
xt_addrtype
xt_conntrack
xt_hl
xt_limit
xt_nat
xt_tcpudp
```

!!ALSA/HDA dmesg
!!--------------

```
[    0.119222] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Dell-Video)
[    0.119222] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
[    0.119222] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-HPI-Hybrid-Graphics)
--
[   41.384067] input: Live! Cam Sync 1080p: Live! Cam as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/input/input18
[   42.023177] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
[   42.107235] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp1s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=2409:4072:0186:ef83:21e9:c7ad:55e3:0184 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=327293 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24
```

!!Packages installed
!!--------------------

```
ii  alsa-oss                                   1.0.28-1ubuntu1                                 amd64        ALSA wrapper for OSS applications
ii  alsa-tools                                 1.1.3-1                                         amd64        Console based ALSA utilities for specific hardware
ii  alsa-tools-gui                             1.1.3-1                                         amd64        GUI based ALSA utilities for specific hardware
ii  alsa-utils                                 1.1.3-1ubuntu1                                  amd64        Utilities for configuring and using ALSA
```

**If anyone can help me out, it will be very much appreciated.**

Comment: easiest way to determine if issue is ( software and/or config ) or hardware is to burn Ubuntu onto a USB stick and boot from that USB stick ... if OK in that boot up then the hardware is fine and issue is either config or software ... added benefit of booting up this way is it also gives you a chance to view a proper working setup ( packages + config )

Comment: See if https://askubuntu.com/questions/1365905/ubuntu-21-04-no-sound-on-new-dell-inspiron-7700-aio helps. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @ScottStensland Thanks, I tried to boot from a live usb. It has been working fine, but audio session in live session shows dummy output.

Comment: @alfredj.stanley Did you try the fix in the answer that I referred to on Nov 16?

Comment: @heynnema Yes, I did, but still no sound, thank you for your help anyway.

Comment: Did you remove or edit the existing "snd_hda_intel: model=laptop position_fix=1" line and replace it with mine?

Comment: @heynnema yes i replaced it with "options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi"

Comment: @heynnema I tried to boot from Elementery OS in demo mode, it also shows not sound output detected, I think my issues are in the hardware.

Comment: Did you reboot after changing the line? Try booting to a Ubuntu Live 21.10 DVD/USB and see if it works there. If you dual-boot with Windows, does sound work there? I don't think it's a hardware problem.

Comment: @heynnema Sorry for the late reply, I uninstalled ubuntu 18 and installed ubuntu 20.04 the audio session is still showing dummy output. I tried every fix suggested on the internet but still no hope. Bluetooth is working, and I can use an external microphone, and the audio jack is not responding to input.

Comment: Did you try booting to a Ubuntu Live 21.10 DVD/USB and see if it works there? I still suspect that it's a parameter to the "snd_hda_intel: model=" option... you just have to figure out which parameter. I'll put together an answer that details a BIOS update...

Answer (score 0):

For some time, I have found that when I reboot my desktop computer (originally Ubuntu 16.04, updated to 18.04), the sound does not work until I unplug and then replug the sound cable from my speakers to my box.

I have no idea if you have cables from your speakers to your box, but if you do, you might try this.

Answer (score 0):

**BIOS**

Dell Vostro 3559

You have an old BIOS version 1.2.6, and there's a newer BIOS available, version 1.8.0, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/vostro-15-3559-laptop/drivers).

**Note**: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your model #.

**Note**: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

**Sound**

Although I haven't been able to provide the correct parameter, I strongly suspect that fixing the sound problem will be an edit to /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf.

examples (only use one at a time):

```
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi

options snd-hda-intel model=dell-vostro position_fix=0 enable=yes

options snd-hda-intel model=auto

options snd-hda-intel model=dell-vostro-3500
```

Then reboot and retest the sound.

For additional info, see:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HdaIntelSoundHowto

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingSoundProblems

https://docs.slackware.com/howtos:hardware:audio_and_snd-hda-intel

https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/sound/hd-audio/notes.html

https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/sound/hd-audio/models.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my bios update. I updated my bios and updated alsa-base.conf file and did reboot after changing it, sadly, it was still showing dummy output. Please refer to the url's and if you find my issue interesting, help me out, it will be very much appreciated, you are my last hope. [https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1T-m7VkOtGfIwGRgNxe8J9AHXEmqi--QF?usp=sharing]

Comment: @alfredj.stanley In your alsa-base.conf file, you only want to enter ONE "options snd-hda-intel model=" line... you added all three. I'll also add some more help links into my answer.

Comment: @alfredj.stanley Note the new 4th example in my answer.