# Ubuntu 20.04 HDMI audio output not working (Intel NUC NUC11PAHi5)

Tags: sound, hdmi

I have Ubuntu 20.04 on an Intel NUC NUC11PAHi5, and can't get HDMI audio output to work. I did notice if I suspend and resume, 2 channel HDMI audio will work, until I reboot, but not 5.1 channel HDMI audio. Is there any instructions to get audio working properly?

I did fix the aux jack that was also not working by following this,[Install Realtek Audio drivers in Ubuntu 20.04 (Intel Nuc nuc10i7fnh)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258583/install-realtek-audio-drivers-in-ubuntu-20-04-intel-nuc-nuc10i7fnh/1360699)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same NUC and was able to get 5.1 working in 22.04.  I ended up using a USB-C to HDMI cable but I still needed to suspend and resume, sometimes several times.  I had issues with channels being swapped too (e.g., center channel playing in front right) which fixed itself through suspend and resume.

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like there's a proper fix (at least I haven't found one) and pipewire in 22.10 isn't any better.  In fact, I can't even get 5.1 to work at all, and it still takes suspend and resume to get 2.0 to work.

Comment: I found this https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000030985/intel-nuc.html but it's quite old and I got error message when I tried it in the terminal, I wonder if there is an updated version?

Comment: I've seen that doc too and had the same result.  I haven't been able to find anything newer.  There's this [forum post](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-NUCs/NUC11TNHi5-HDMI-audio-issue-on-Ubuntu-22-04/m-p/1379756#M90764) with users experiencing the same, or similiar, with no luck too.

Comment: Well that post was depressing to read ;/

Comment: Wait, I'm a bit confused, you said 5.1 works with USB-C to HDMI after a few times suspending. Once it works does it permanently stay until reboot? But then you also said you can't get 5.1 to work at all?

Comment: No, it does not persist between reboots.  I was able to get 5.1 to work in 22.04, not 22.10.  Also, when using something like VLC, it would cause 5.1 to stop working sometimes due to audio codec changes.

Comment: One thing you can try in `/etc/pulse/default.pa` is commenting out `load-module module-suspend-on-idle`.  I think that helped me with the channels reverting back when I left the computer idle when I did get 5.1 working.