Looking for sound drivers MSI
I have an old MSI board, B550-M Pro VDH WiFi, that I downloaded drivers for it. I need the audio drivers, which are not available any longer. They claim they have never made Linux divers...but I had them!
My headphones work, my speakers do not, except for a pop when I reboot.
MSI is at a total loss. My drives got formatted, due to a virus, which has been eliminated.
Does anyone know where I got these things? I think they were ALSA drivers? but maybe not or an add on to them?
If so, email me at jim.petrosino  @ gmail.com or tweet me @ therealcyber5
Thanks

You've not provided the basic starting point, ie. what Ubuntu product & release you're using. Ubuntu LTS releases have kernel stack choice, changing the kernel means kernel modules also change (kernel modules commonly called drivers) so providing details of your software stack is the starting point. What Ubuntu product & release are you using?

Have you tried https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258583/install-realtek-audio-drivers-in-ubuntu-20-04-intel-nuc-nuc10i7fnh ?
