# Only Dummy Output appears in Sound Settings

Tags: sound, 20.04, soundcard

My sound just ceased to be from one day to the next, in Ubuntu 20.04.

No sound card appears in sound settings except Dummy output.

```
$ pacmd list-cards
0 card(s) available.


$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio:
09:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:0fbb] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ZOTAC International (MCO) Ltd. GM204 High Definition Audio Controller [19da:1366]
0a:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Function [1022:148a]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Function [1022:148a]
--
0b:00.4 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller [1022:1487]
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller [1849:1202]
```

None of the solutions on the following thread worked for me:

[Only "Dummy output" (sound) in Ubuntu 20.04 after reboot - Broken driver / module](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258510/only-dummy-output-sound-in-ubuntu-20-04-after-reboot-broken-driver-modul)

Any thoughts would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It seems the loss of the sound card was due to upgrading the kernel from 5.6.0-64 to 5.8.0-38.

Here is the solution:

1. Boot to 5.4.0-64
2. Hold the current Kernel version:

   ```
   sudo apt-mark hold 5.4.0-64-generic
   ```
3. Remove the latest kernel upgrade version:

   ```
   sudo apt remove -y $(dpkg -l | grep -o -P "linux-[\S]*-5.8.0[\d\S]+")
   ```
4. Update the repositories and auto-remove the unwanted installations:

   ```
   sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade && sudo apt autoremove
   ```
5. Restart the system for the changes to take place

   ```
   reboot
   ```

In the future, to revert to kernel upgrades, we can do:

```
sudo apt-mark unhold 5.4.0-64-generic
```