# No sound in Ubuntu 20.04 after driver mess

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

So i tried to install realtek drivers on my pc. 'Rt linux HDaudio 5.18'. Then i followed the steps in the manual:

> Installation:
> This Source Code is from [www.alsa-project.org](http://www.alsa-project.org).
> For OS installation, please remember add the Development tool kit.
> For driver installation, please follow below steps.
>
> Note: Please check Development tool kit on your OS.
>
> Manual install:
> Step 1. unzip source code
> tar xfvj alsa-driver-1.0.xx.tar.bz2
>
> Step 2. Complied source code
> a. cd alsa-driver-1.0.xx
> b. ./configure --with-cards=hda-intel
> c. make
> d. make install
>
> Step 3. reboot your machine
>
> Step 4. Use the alsamixer the disable mute (All audio line default is mute)
> excute alsamixer
>
> Note:  1. The most detail information, can refer the alsa-kernel/Documenttation/ALSA-Configuration.txt in the azx-021705.tar.bz2.
> 2. Kernel Version must be 2.6 or later.
> 3. All mixer channels are muted by default. You must use a native
> or OSS mixer program to unmute appropriate channels.
> 4. If can not compile the source code, try to rename the /usr/src/linux-2.x -> /usr/src/linux.
> 5. The driver added to support the SPDIF functoin.
> 6. a. You can download the alsa-lib-1.0.x and alsa-utils-1.0.x form the [www.alsa-project.org](http://www.alsa-project.org), then unzip and install them.
> b. Suggest use "alsamixer" to control mixer function.
> c. Used "alsaconf" can autodetect which drive you need to install (step 4).
> 7. SUSE Distribution must install the ncurses package.

After that it gave me some error so i tried installing it again but the same error appeared. So i gave up on this and continued my work.
On the next day (today) i turned on my computer and noticed that i have no audio. In the sound settings on 'output device' i have 'dummy output'. So i tried to fix it by reinstalling 'alsa' and 'pulseaudio' drivers, that didn't helped. I installed 'inxi' package and ran it with -SMA parameters. That's what i got:
[image link?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oj6rS.png)

```
kysaba@apollo:~$ sudo alsa force-reload
[sudo] password for kysaba: 
Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: (none loaded).
Loading ALSA sound driver modules: (none to reload).
kysaba@apollo:~$ inxi -SMA
System:
  Host: apollo Kernel: 5.8.0-44-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
  Desktop: Gnome 3.36.4 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:
  Type: Desktop Mobo: ASUSTeK model: MAXIMUS VIII RANGER v: Rev 1.xx 
  serial: <superuser/root required> UEFI [Legacy]: American Megatrends 
  v: 2202 date: 09/19/2016 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel 100 Series/C230 Series Family HD Audio driver: N/A 
  Device-2: NVIDIA GP107GL High Definition Audio driver: N/A
```

So i guess the problem is with these N/A driver things. I tried to google it but only got the solution that i already tried, like reinstalling alsa and pulseaudio.

And help hands with this?

Comment: Did you find any answer useful? Providing feedback is useful for the community.

Answer (score 0):

Follow [Only "Dummy output" (sound) in Ubuntu 20.04 after reboot - Broken driver / module](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258510/only-dummy-output-sound-in-ubuntu-20-04-after-reboot-broken-driver-modul) and post outputs.

In addition to the recommended set of initial diagnostic series of commands, I guess in the end the most likely commands that would help you are:

```
$ modprobe --show-depends snd_hda_intel
$ sudo apt-get install linux-modules-extra-<your kernel version>-generic
```

and reboot.