# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop 64-bit - HDMI output can be selected but there is no sound output

Tags: 20.04, sound, hdmi

There are several solutions on the internet, none of them work for me.

[image]

Using pavucontrol and starting a song, it says audio comes out but in reality there is no sound output.

[image]

I use HDMI to HDMI cable.
I have already checked that the monitor audio is enabled.

Comment: Do you use a HDMI-HDMI cable, or do you use a DisplayPort-HDMI cable, or an HDMI-DisplayPort cable or even a DisplayPort-DisplayPort cable?

Comment: I use HDMI to HDMI cable.

Comment: Stupid question, but do you have enabled audio at your monitor?

Comment: I have already checked that the monitor audio is enabled.

Comment: Does sound come out if using a different device?
It would help a lot if you post the output of commands 1-9 and 12-13 of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258510/only-dummy-output-sound-in-ubuntu-20-04-after-reboot-broken-driver-modul

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

If you use the Ubuntu 20.04 tool to Test the speakers don't rely on that. Sometimes doesn't work.

Better play a video with a program like VLC. Ideally don't use the browser with youtube as sound may be muted for certain windows. Check your settings and that things like system Sounds are not muted.

[image]

Also when my monitor entered powersave I was losing the Audio, so to make it work I was restarting it with:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

I explained how I made it work in my blog:

https://blog.carlesmateo.com/2020/10/13/fixing-problems-with-audio-not-sounding-after-upgrade-from-ubuntu-18-04-lts-to-20-04-1-lts/

Also it may seem a silly question, but make sure your monitor has speakers.
Many monitors have control volume because they have a jack to connect earphones but they don't have speakers.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This can sometimes be resolved by forcing PulseAudio to re-initialise its cached configuration files:

```
sudo killall pulseaudio
rm -rf ~/.config/pulse/*
rm -rf ~/.pulse*
```

Once cleared, reboot the machine. You should be good to go again. I've never had to do this more than once on a machine.