# Dummy output issue after installing Gstreamer and ALSA plugins in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, plugins, gstreamer

I had installed Gstreamer and ALSA plugins to work on some experiments.
Steps followed for the installation of the plugin: https://tsn.readthedocs.io/avb.html#plugins-installation

However, after the installation was completed I restarted my PC after which the audio has stopped working. In the setting in the output device, dummy output shows up while for the input device there is no option. I have dual boot in my system so, in Windows, the audio works fine, thus it's clearly not a hardware problem.

I uninstalled the plugins as well as tried reinstalling Ubuntu audio drivers, however, the issue still persists. I believe while setting up the plugins some configuration has changed.

Ubuntu Version: 20.04

Linux Kernel Version: 5.11.0-27-generic

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please add all output listed in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258510/only-dummy-output-sound-in-ubuntu-20-04-after-reboot-broken-driver-modul so you provide others with enough information.

Answer (score 0):

There is a range of possible causes

You could try

1. Updating the kernel and/or installing `linux-modules-extra`
2. `alsa`

   ```
    sudo apt install --reinstall alsa-base pulseaudio
    sudo alsa force-reload
   ```
3. `timidity`

   ```
    sudo apt purge timidity-daemon
   ```
4. Driver config

   ```
    echo "options snd-hda-intel model=generic" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
    echo "options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
   ```

---

If the above doesn't work, I suggest you add all output listed in [Only "Dummy output" (sound) in Ubuntu 20.04 after reboot - Broken driver / module](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258510/only-dummy-output-sound-in-ubuntu-20-04-after-reboot-broken-driver-modul) .
It would take you some 5 minutes...

Comment: Thanks a lot for proposing these solutions, however, the issue isn't fixed, still the audio isn't working.