# No sound after Installing UBUNTU 22.04.1 on my Windows 11 pc

Tags: sound

I installed UBUNTU 22.04.1 on my laptop and I don’t have sound. I have tried `pulse -k` but it hasn’t helped.
Sound worked okay on Windows.
Settings - sound - output shows: Dummy Output
Running the command: `lspci -nnk | grep-A2 Audio` give me the following:

```
00:0e.0 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor High Definition Audio [8086:3198] (rev 06)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Sound
    Subsystem: Device [2782:0303]
```

I really need your help. Thanks.

Comment: is it related to the same issue [reported here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1361424/no-sound-with-ubuntu-on-chuwi-gemibook-pro) and like that post, does your windows sound work OK? Please [edit] your question accordingly to bring it back to focus.