# No sound - only "Dummy output" (sound) in Ubuntu 20.04 on reformatted Pixelbook

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, chromebook

Some time ago I installed Ubuntu 20.04 (after removing ChromeOS) from a Google PixelBook. Just this week the sound (which worked fine before) stopped working: speakers, headphones, internal microphone all don't work.
Specifically, I'm running:

```
> uname -ar
Linux chromepy 5.15.0-41-generic #44~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 24 13:27:29 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Advice/suggestions would be appreciated! I know that this question has been asked before (e.g. [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258510/only-dummy-output-sound-in-ubuntu-20-04-after-reboot-broken-driver-modul) and other places), but none of these steps seem to work for me.

A full dump of diagnostics is below, but in short: the only clearly FAILED diagnostics (to me) seem to be:

1. Sound/microphone don't work
2. "Dummy output" is only output option in the (Settings > Sound) GUI.
3. Entering `pacmd list-cards` yields `0 card(s) available.`
4. Attempting `sudo alsa force-reload` just causes the computer to freeze; I have to reboot.

On the other hand, other diagnostics that seem (to me!) to yield OK results include:

1. The asound/cards file is present:

```
> cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [kblr55145663max]: kbl-r5514-5663- - kbl-r5514-5663-max
                      Google-Eve-1.0
```

2. `lsmod` shows plenty of results:

```
> lsmod | grep snd 
42:snd_soc_kbl_rt5663_rt5514_max98927    28672  0
43:snd_soc_hdac_hdmi      36864  1 snd_soc_kbl_rt5663_rt5514_max98927
44:snd_soc_skl_ssp_clk    16384  3
45:snd_soc_dmic           16384  0
74:snd_soc_skl           172032  1 snd_soc_skl_ssp_clk
77:snd_soc_hdac_hda       24576  1 snd_soc_skl
79:snd_hda_ext_core       32768  3 snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl
81:snd_soc_sst_ipc        20480  1 snd_soc_skl
82:snd_soc_sst_dsp        32768  1 snd_soc_skl
87:snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    61440  1 snd_soc_skl
88:snd_soc_acpi           16384  2 snd_soc_acpi_intel_match,snd_soc_skl
94:snd_hda_intel          53248  0
97:snd_intel_dspcfg       28672  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_soc_skl
98:snd_intel_sdw_acpi     20480  1 snd_intel_dspcfg
100:snd_hda_codec         155648  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_soc_hdac_hda
103:snd_hda_core          106496  6 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl
104:snd_soc_rt5514         49152  1
105:snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
106:snd_soc_rt5663         81920  2 snd_soc_kbl_rt5663_rt5514_max98927
108:snd_soc_max98927       28672  2
109:snd_soc_rt5514_spi     16384  2 snd_soc_rt5514
111:snd_soc_rl6231         20480  2 snd_soc_rt5514,snd_soc_rt5663
114:snd_soc_core          327680  9 snd_soc_max98927,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_rt5514,snd_soc_skl,snd_soc_rt5514_spi,snd_soc_kbl_rt5663_rt5514_max98927,snd_soc_dmic,snd_soc_rt5663
117:snd_compress           24576  1 snd_soc_core
119:ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
120:snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
122:snd_pcm               135168  12 snd_hda_intel,snd_soc_max98927,snd_hda_codec,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_soc_skl,snd_soc_rt5514_spi,snd_soc_kbl_rt5663_rt5514_max98927,snd_soc_rt5663,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
123:snd_seq_midi           20480  0
124:snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
127:snd_rawmidi            45056  1 snd_seq_midi
139:snd_seq                73728  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
144:snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
145:snd_timer              40960  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
146:snd                   102400  12 snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_soc_kbl_rt5663_rt5514_max98927,snd_rawmidi
148:soundcore              16384  1 snd
```

3. plenty of `snd` modules:

```
> dpkg -L linux-modules-$(uname -r) | grep snd
/lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-dummy.ko
/lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-midi-emul.ko
/lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-midi-event.ko
/lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-midi.ko
/lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq-virmidi.ko
/lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/kernel/sound/core/seq/snd-seq.ko
/lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-compress.ko
/lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-ctl-led.ko
/lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-hrtimer.ko
/lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-hwdep.ko
/lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-pcm-dmaengine.ko
/lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-pcm.ko
/lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-rawmidi.ko
/lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-seq-device.ko
/lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-timer.ko
/lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd.ko
/lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/kernel/sound/drivers/pcsp/snd-pcsp.ko
/lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/kernel/sound/pci/snd-ens1370.ko
```

4. `inxi` detects an audio driver:

```
> inxi -SA
System:
  Host: chromepy Kernel: 5.15.0-41-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
  Desktop: Gnome 3.36.4 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio driver: snd_soc_skl 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.15.0-41-generic
```

5. `lspci` shows an audio controller:

```
> lspci -nnk | grep -A 1 Audio
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [8086:9d71] (rev 21)
    DeviceName: Multimedia audio controller
    Subsystem: Google, Inc. Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [1ae0:006b]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_soc_skl
```

6. `aplay` detects playback devices:

```
> aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: kblr55145663max [kbl-r5514-5663-max], device 0: Audio (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: kblr55145663max [kbl-r5514-5663-max], device 2: Headset Audio (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: kblr55145663max [kbl-r5514-5663-max], device 6: Hdmi1 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: kblr55145663max [kbl-r5514-5663-max], device 7: Hdmi2 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

7. `lshw` detects an audio controller:

```
> lshw -C multimedia
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-multimedia              
       description: Multimedia audio controller
       product: Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
       version: 21
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_soc_skl latency=64
       resources: irq:16 memory:d122c000-d122ffff memory:d1210000-d121ffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

8. alsa modules seem to be installed:

```
> dpkg -l | grep alsa
ii  alsa-base                                                   1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5                  all          ALSA driver configuration files
ii  alsa-topology-conf                                          1.2.2-1                               all          ALSA topology configuration files
ii  alsa-ucm-conf                                               1.2.2-1ubuntu0.6                      all          ALSA Use Case Manager configuration files
ii  alsa-utils                                                  1.2.2-1ubuntu2.1                      amd64        Utilities for configuring and using ALSA
ii  gstreamer1.0-alsa:amd64                                     1.16.2-4ubuntu0.1                     amd64        GStreamer plugin for ALSA
```

9. alsa_base.conf contents:

```
> grep intel /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf 
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
```

10. `arecord` shows hardware capture devices:

```
> arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: kblr55145663max [kbl-r5514-5663-max], device 1: Audio Record (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: kblr55145663max [kbl-r5514-5663-max], device 3: Echoreference Capture snd-soc-dummy-dai-3 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: kblr55145663max [kbl-r5514-5663-max], device 4: dmiccap (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: kblr55145663max [kbl-r5514-5663-max], device 5: Wake on Voice snd-soc-dummy-dai-5 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

11. No sound either if I plug earphones (or if I plug in and reboot).
12. I have no timidity-daemon to remove.

Suggestions? Please help!

Comment: did you found https://github.com/alsa-project/alsa-ucm-conf/issues/108

Comment: Thanks - I took a look at that, but the only hint I could find there was to try commenting out the SectionDevice.Headphones -- but that has no effect.  In my kblr55145663max HiFi.conf file, the 'codec1' setting mentioned in that Github issue was already set to 'on'.  Maybe there's more advice to be gleaned from that Issue, but I'm not expert enough to decode it.