# No sound on an HP 15z-fc000 after warm boot

Tags: sound, 22.04, reboot, 23.04

I have an HP 15z-fc000 that won't play sound from its built-in speakers after a warm boot (i.e., after doing "reboot"). It works fine after a cold boot (i.e., after doing "shutdown", waiting for it to turn completely off, and then turning it back on with the power button). When it's not working, the name of the output device I see is "Dummy output". Here's the relevant device from `lspci -vvvnn` from a warm boot when it's broken:

```
03:00.6 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller [1022:15e3]
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller [103c:8b2f]
        Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
        Interrupt: pin C routed to IRQ 54
        IOMMU group: 17
        Region 0: Memory at fccc0000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
        Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
                Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
        Capabilities: [64] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
                DevCap: MaxPayload 256 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <4us, L1 unlimited
                        ExtTag+ AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset- SlotPowerLimit 0.000W
                DevCtl: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq-
                        RlxdOrd+ ExtTag+ PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+
                        MaxPayload 256 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
                DevSta: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
                LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 16GT/s, Width x16, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <64ns, L1 <1us
                        ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp+
                LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes, Disabled- CommClk+
                        ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
                LnkSta: Speed 16GT/s (ok), Width x16 (ok)
                        TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
                DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range ABCD, TimeoutDis+ NROPrPrP- LTR-
                         10BitTagComp+ 10BitTagReq- OBFF Not Supported, ExtFmt+ EETLPPrefix+, MaxEETLPPrefixes 1
                         EmergencyPowerReduction Not Supported, EmergencyPowerReductionInit-
                         FRS- TPHComp- ExtTPHComp-
                         AtomicOpsCap: 32bit- 64bit- 128bitCAS-
                DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis- LTR- OBFF Disabled,
                         AtomicOpsCtl: ReqEn-
                LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -3.5dB, EqualizationComplete- EqualizationPhase1-
                         EqualizationPhase2- EqualizationPhase3- LinkEqualizationRequest-
                         Retimer- 2Retimers- CrosslinkRes: unsupported
        Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
                Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
        Capabilities: [100 v1] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
        Capabilities: [2a0 v1] Access Control Services
                ACSCap: SrcValid- TransBlk- ReqRedir- CmpltRedir- UpstreamFwd- EgressCtrl- DirectTrans-
                ACSCtl: SrcValid- TransBlk- ReqRedir- CmpltRedir- UpstreamFwd- EgressCtrl- DirectTrans-
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

On cold boots when it's working, it has `DisINTx+` instead of `DisINTx-`, `MSI: Enable+` instead of `MSI: Enable-`, and `Address: 00000000fee00000` instead of `Address: 0000000000000000`.

On warm boots when it's broken, I don't see this device in `aplay -l` at all, but on cold boots when it's working, it appears there like this:

```
card 1: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC236 Analog [ALC236 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I've tried on both Ubuntu 22.04 (a clean installation, not an upgrade from an older version) and 23.04 (from a live USB), and neither one works. I'm happy to use either, should there be a solution that works on one but not the other. Here's some other things I tried, and the results:

- Adding `snd-hda-intel.model=generic` to the kernel command line, or appending `options snd-hda-intel model=generic` to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` - Changes the output device I see to "HD-Audio Generic Digital Stereo (HDMI)", but I still can't hear anything played through it.
- Adding `snd-hda-intel.dmic_detect=0` to the kernel command line, or appending `options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0` to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` - No noticeable change
- Both of the above at the same time - No noticeable change beyond what the first one did alone
- Booting the 6.3.0 mainline kernel from [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v6.3/amd64/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v6.3/amd64/) - No noticeable change
- `pulseaudio --kill` followed by `pulseaudio --start`: PulseAudio never comes back up and I can't even see sound preferences anymore until I reboot
- `sudo touch /usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d/with-pulseaudio` followed by `systemctl --user restart pipewire-session-manager`: No noticeable change

I'm out of ideas. What should I try/do next?

Comment: Try this method: https://github.com/HewlettPackard/zhpe-driver

Comment: @Logan That driver has nothing whatsoever to do with audio.

Comment: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=79700

Comment: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=211494

Comment: Do you have another card that may be messing with audio? See
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/736659/disable-pci-sound-card-with-udev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After receiving a helpful bit of information from [Ruslan](https://askubuntu.com/users/1695546/ruslan), namely that this used to work fine in prior Ubuntu versions, I managed to confirm that this is a kernel regression caused by commit [`5aec98913095ed3b4424ed6c5fdeb6964e9734da`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?h=master&id=5aec98913095). I reported this as https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=217440 and am working around it for now by doing a custom kernel build with that change reverted. Regzbot link: https://linux-regtracking.leemhuis.info/regzbot/regression/bugzilla.kernel.org/217440/

Answer (score 1):

There exists a sort of "canonical set" of commands that I wrote, and it helped many others diagnosing (and then solving) audio issues.
In particular, if you see "Dummy output".

Please check [Only "Dummy output" (sound) in Ubuntu 20.04 after reboot - Broken driver / module](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258510/only-dummy-output-sound-in-ubuntu-20-04-after-reboot-broken-driver-modul)
and post whatever results you find.

Comment: The problem still exists after looking through everything there, but I did make one new discovery while trying it all: this problem only occurs after warm boots (reboots), and sound works fine on the first boot after cold boots (powering all the way off and then back on). I edited details about this into my question, including differences between the outputs of some commands.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica - I suggest you post in the question the output of each of the commands listed in the link. It may provide useful information.

Answer (score 1):

The same problem with the same laptop. First time it works, then after reboot - it does not (dummy output). What I found additionally is that Ubuntu 21.10 still works *fine* at least in this respect (i.e., you can reboot without any issues). However, Ubuntu 22.04 (the very first release) with Linux 5.15 does *not* work fine any more. If I remember correctly, Ubuntu 21.10 still used Linux 5.13. That means the issue was most likely introduced in the driver somewhere in between 5.13 and 5.15.

Another thing I noticed is that sound device identifiers are enumerated differently:

1. In Ubuntu 22.04+, we have:

cat /sys/class/sound/hwC1D0/subsystem_id  :  0xaa0100

cat /sys/class/sound/hwC2D0/subsystem_id  :  0x103c8b30

2. In Ubuntu 21.10, we have:

cat /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/subsystem_id  :  0xaa0100

cat /sys/class/sound/hwC1D0/subsystem_id  :  0x103c8b30

Note that in Ubuntu 21.10 it starts from hwC0D0, but in Ubuntu 22.04+ it starts from hwC1D0. Furthermore, after reboot hwC2D0 completely *disappears*.

Is the codec (hwC2D0) is somehow powered off when the driver is unloaded?

Comment: The fact that it works in the old kernel is incredibly useful, thanks! I'm going to bisect and see if that lets me track the problem down completely.