No sound coming from HP Ubuntu Laptop
After installing regular Ubuntu 24.04 on my HP laptop, there's no sound. When I try to turn up the volume it just says "Dummy Output". I can't connect wired headphones to it, nor can I use Bluetooth. I REALLY need help. I can't live without audio, and I want to use Ubuntu as my main.

See here: https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/
and here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258510/only-dummy-output-sound-in-ubuntu-20-04-after-reboot-broken-driver-modul

Does this answer your question? Only "Dummy output" (sound) in Ubuntu 20.04 after reboot - Broken driver / module

By any chance is this a chromebook? If not, what is the model name of the laptop?

Please edit the question and post the output of the command inxi -SMA

UPDATE: For some reason, when I did a full shutdown, and powered it back on, that fixed it. I have no idea why it was not working the first time.
